# Open sets question

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm completely stuck on this question: Show that the set
$$
U = \{(w,x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^4}: |wz - xy| > 1\}
$$
is open.

I've tried approaching it from limits, open balls etc but doesn't lead to anything. I feel as thought I'm missing something.

Comment: The set is the inverse image under a continuous function of the open set $(1,\infty )$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint :**
$$U = f^{-1}\left((1, +\infty)\right)$$

where $f : \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the *continuous* function defined for all $(w,x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^4}$ by $$f(w,x,y,z)=|wz - xy|$$

Comment: the equation has a condition : $|wz - xy| > 1$, which means that the set admits values that yield a value greater than $1$. Is it the same thing you said ?

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: the set contains values of the variables greater than the ones that yield a result of 1, right ?

Comment: The set contains elements of $\mathbb{R}^4$. Therefore, saying that some elements of the set are "greater" than other means nothing (you cannot compare elements of $\mathbb{R}^4$... or you have to tell me which order you consider)

Comment: that is not what I meant. There's a relation that must be satisfied for the set of values from $\mathbb{R}^4$ to be in the required set. So, the required values must be the ones for which the relation must evaluate to a value greater than $1$, right ?

Comment: Yes, this is the definition of the set $U$.

Comment: Thanks then, @TheSilverDoe

Answer (score 0):

One very important fact about open sets and continuous functions is that the inverse image of an open set under a continuous function is open. In that case, if you look at the function:

$$f:(w,x,y,z)\to |wz-xy|$$
then your set is $f^{-1}(]1,\infty[)$ and is open.

Comment: In my opinion, your statement is a very important fact about *continuity*, rather than about open sets.

Comment: You are right, I edited the post :)

Answer (score 0):

$\epsilon$ and $\delta$ say hello.

Let $(w_1,x_1,y_1,z_1)$ be any element in $U$.

This means that there exists an explicit value $\delta_1 > 0$ 
such that $|w_1z_1 - x_1y_1| = \delta_1 + 1.$

The challenge is to exhibit a neighborhood around $(w_1, x_1, y_1, z_1)$ that
is completely contained in $U$.

Choose $\delta$ so that

$$\delta \times \left\{ ~|w_1| + |x_1| + |y_1| + |z_1| ~\right\} + 2\delta^2 < \delta_1.$$

For simplicity, consider the neighborhood formed by a 4d-cube, rather than a 4d-sphere:

$$T = \{(w,x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^4} ~: 
|w - w_1| < \delta, |x - x_1| < \delta, |y - y_1| < \delta, |z - z_1| < \delta \}.$$

Let $(w,x,y,z)$ be any element in $T$.

Then, there exists $a,b$ such that $-\delta < a,b < \delta$ and 
$w = (w_1 + a), z = (z_1 + b)$.

Then,

$$|zw - z_1w_1| = |az_1 + bw_1 + ab| \leq
(|a|\times |z_1|) + (|b| \times |w_1|) + (|a| \times |b|)$$

$$ < \delta \times \left( |z_1| + |w_1| \right) + \delta^2.$$

Identical analysis gives

$$|xy - x_1y_1| < \delta \times \left( |x_1| + |y_1| \right) + \delta^2.$$

Then

$$ |(wz - xy) - (w_1z_1 - x_1y_1)| ~\leq~
|wz - w_1z_1| + |xy - x_1y_1| < \delta_1 ~\Rightarrow$$

$$|wz - xy| > 1.$$